# How to Change TextField's hintText FontFamily in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

```dart
Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0, bottom: 30.0),
  height: 50.0,
  padding:
  EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 5.0),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.white,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(29.5)),
  child: TextField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      hintText: 'Search', /////////////////////////////////Here See It
      icon: SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/search.svg'),
      border: InputBorder.none),
  ),
),
```

[image]

How to Change TextField's hintText FontFamily in the flutter u can see it on the image what I am trying to say

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [hintStyle](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration/hintStyle.html) property of `InputDecoration` and assign `TextStyle` to it then add `fontFamily`.

```dart
InputDecoration(
    hintText: 'Search',
    hintStyle: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'some-font'),
)
```